# Use Print library to set string variable

Tags: serial, c++, print

I need a function that has the basic functionality of the Print library, accepting different kinds of argument types and parsing them. However, I would like to then store the result in a string/char array. Does anybody know how I might utilize the Print library to do so?

Comment: RTFM: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringConstructor

Comment: Sorry. I typically work in C. I didn't realize the string constructor was so robust. Thanks.

Comment: my StreamLib published in 2018 has CStringBuilder

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the functionality of `Print` by creating your own class
that inherits from it. For this, you only need to implement the
`size_t write(uint8_t)` method that prints a single character. Here is a
simple class that inherits from both `Print` and `String`, i.e. you get
a `String` you can `print()` and `println()` into:

```
// A String you can print() and println() into.
class PrintString : public Print, public String
{
public:
    PrintString() : String() {}

    size_t write(uint8_t c) {
        *this += (char) c;
        return 1;
    }
};
```

And here is how you could use it:

```
PrintString answer;
answer.print("The answer is ");
answer.println(42);
```